# Should I build a REST api for AJAX web application elements?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, rest

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127228/should-a-web-app-use-its-own-public-api-to-display-data) question and it brought up some questions about building a RESTful API. For my application, I want to make something similar to Twitter or Facebook's newsfeed where it uses AJAX to pull additional feed information as the user scrolls through the page using jQuery. I am not sure what's the best approach to architect this. Is it overkill to create a REST api to expose this functionality that I only intend to use in my own web application? What are some tradeoffs I need to consider?

Note: the project is using PHP/CodeIgniter/jQuery

Comment: I think that this question is too general, but even more specifically it's probably better for programmers

Answer (score 0):

Consider the language that PHP and Javascript both talk best at - and that's JSON. So, unless you want the full RESTful services, why do anything more complex than JSON?

RESTful is really designed for supporting a wide range of services. You only need the one. Don't make it more complex for yourself.